# Can I upgrade the resolution of a camera without getting a new camera body?

Tags: resolution

Can you upgrade your camera body with higher resolution? E.g with a new sensor? 
I would even be willing to pay for a whole camera to upgrade the one I have.
The reason I want to upgrade the sensor and keep the same camera is that it fits a $3k underwater housing and new cameras will not work with this housing.

Comment: What resolution and size of sensor do you have now ?  What do you need the extra resolution for ?

Comment: Why would you want to keep the old body? Buying a newer body with higher resolution would not only be cheaper, it would generally also give you higher ISO, better low light performance, and faster processing speed.

Comment: I do underwater photography with small amounts of video. If I replace the camera I would need to replace the dive housing and those are $3k to $5k. The camera is the cheap part.

Comment: We're going to need to know the current camera to see if there's any options that leap to mind (which is not likely IMO - cases are built to match the camera bodies).  Do you really need more resolution ?  I'd have thought low light performance was your main issue underwater.

Comment: What camera and underwater housing are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you should be selling the camera and the housing as a matched set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a dSLR sensor be replaced with one that belongs to another model?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/95294/can-a-dslr-sensor-be-replaced-with-one-that-belongs-to-another-model)

Answer (score 4):

Cameras are built around the sensor: firmware, processing unit, exposure measurement system, AF system... so you are really asking about taking the innards of a recent camera and putting them in an old body.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer but wanted to check to make sure.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you're shooting medium format with a replaceable digital back, no. The sensor is the guts of the camera, and are not replaceable.

I don't know if it's feasible at all, but maybe use a longer lens and shoot/stitch panos to get higher resolution?

Comment: Stitching isn't likely to work well with the constant movement of underwater subjects and environment.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm aware, hence the "don't know if it's feasible", but it's the only thing I could think of that would increase resolution, and with enough coverage in time (as well as space) you can sometimes eliminate ghosts/clones.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something specific in mind.. Because for example 5D Mark III and 5DS, 5DSr have so close physical dimensions and controls you may not need new housing.

About replacing the sensor even if someone succeed to replace and position it (related to focusing subsystem) with high probability your firmware may not recognize it and will not work. And to change the firmware... task become very complex.

Comment: Thank you,  I assumed that would be the case but thought I would double check. Was hoping to find a way to safe a few thousand.